# Mac App Store security IAP (or receipt verification) for educational content

Tags: macos, xcode4, in-app-purchase, mac-app-store

For **receipt validation** of an application that provides educational content to students, do I need to use `In-App purchase` or it will be fine with only `Receipt validation`?